# The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it

Tags: usb

I am getting the above fault with my computer. (The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it) It started not so long ago (Before the clean install) on select USB ports. I have just completed a complete clean install for my computer, having wiped the SSD clean. I'm still getting this error. Some devices work and some don't. I have a wacom tablet that works with one of the ports, yet my USB amp wont work with the same port. Same goes with other misc usb devices.

I'd greatly appreciate some help to resolve this issue as it is pretty annoying!

Comment: Sounds like a lack of power, and/or a failing USB subsystem on the motherboard. Try a bigger, known-good PSU, and/or try a replacement motherboard.

Comment: I doubt it would be a lac of power. I'm using a 650w corsair. It's only powering a i7 4770k, SSD, one HDD, 560ti and a asrock extreme 6 z87 mobo. I've previously ran a r9 290x on this rig, before it had to be RMA'd.

I've not got a spare mobo that is up to date. Only an old one from back when i was running the e8400. Same goes with the PSU.

Comment: if you did a clean install and the problem remains, then it's most likely a hardware problem (maybe driver, but for standard USB I highly doubt it).  The way to diagnose hardware suspects is to swap them for known-good parts. If you have no known-good parts to test with, you'll need to get some, or take the machine to a professional repair shop who should have such things available to them. But you never know, someone may come up with an alternate suggestion.

Comment: I forgot to mention.. I've also got a dell monitor with built in 3.0 ports. These also fail to work when connected to the rear I/O panel. 

Ahh, I don't want to go near any repair shop. They seem to drain your wallet before they even look at the pc. I'm confident that I could diagnose the issue with the help of you guys. I'm a DIY type of person!

Comment: Which version of windows? Did you install all the needed drivers after clean install?